# SLES 11.3 zypper over local repository has missing packages

Tags: linux, opensuse, zypper

SLES 11.3 zypper over local repository has missing packages

Trying to install Apache Ambari over SLES 11.3, I downloaded a full repo tarball. Then I created a local repository over the uncompresed files:

```
zypper addrepo /root/SW/ambari/ambari/suse11/2.6.0.0-267 ambari
zypper refresh 
zypper packages -r ambari
```

It yields:

```
   S | Repository | Name                       | Version     | Arch
   --+------------+----------------------------+-------------+-------
     | ambari     | ambari-infra-solr          | 2.6.0.0-267 | noarch
     | ambari     | ambari-infra-solr-client   | 2.6.0.0-267 | noarch
     | ambari     | ambari-logsearch-logfeeder | 2.6.0.0-267 | noarch
     | ambari     | ambari-logsearch-portal    | 2.6.0.0-267 | noarch
     | ambari     | ambari-metrics-common      | 2.6.0.0-267 | noarch
```

There are missing packages like ambari-server 2.6.0.0-267 x86_64. Why?

There are 12 packages while zypper only is aware about 5 of them:

```
# find "/root/SW/ambari/ambari/suse11/2.6.0.0-267" -name "*.rpm" -print | wc -l
12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because we have installed a 32 bits openSuse operating system

```
# uname -m
i686
```

Zypper is clever enough to only show the packages it can install acording to the destination platform. It doesn't show the x86_64 packages like:

```
 ambari-server-2.6.0.0-267.x86_64.rpm
```